# Vue.js 2.0 bootstrap app.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a strange problem that I do not understand. So I've made one main App.vue instance. I bootstrap it like this:

```
import Strip    from './Components/Shared/Strip.vue';
import Bar      from './Components/Shared/Bar.vue';
import App      from './Components/App.vue';
import router   from './router';
import Vue      from 'vue'

/**
 * We'll register all global components here. So we will be able to use it
 * across the entire application.
 */

Vue.component('bar', Bar);
Vue.component('strip', Strip);

/**
 * We'll require a bootstrap file where all important things are being initialized.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

/**
 * We'll bind the vue instance to #app. That's being used in the main
 * index.blade.php file.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Then in my `App.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <navigation></navigation>
        <main>
            <router-view
                    transition
                    transition-mode="out-in">
            </router-view>
        </main>
        <mainfooter>Company</mainfooter>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Auth         from "../Services/Authentication/Auth";
    import Navigation   from './Shared/Navigation.vue';
    import Mainfooter   from './Shared/Footer.vue';
    import Swal         from 'sweetalert';

    export default {
        components: { Navigation, Mainfooter },

        data() {
            return {
                user: { role: 1 },
                authenticated: false
            }
        },

        methods: {
            userHasLoggedIn(user) {
                this.user = user;
                this.authenticated = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I try to access `app.vue` within my `Navigation.vue` for example:

```
{{ this.$root.authenticated }}
```

Nothing shows up. And when I look in `vuedevtools` the user object is not set on the main `root` instance.

[image]

What on earth do I've to do to get this to work!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access data of root component: `authenticated` in  the child component: `Navigation`, it is not possible directly.

You can pass it as [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props) to the Navigation, which is a standard practive to send data to child components in vue.

You have to make following changes for this. add a option [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props) in Navigation vue, like following:

```
Vue.component('navigation', {
  // declare the props
  props: ['authenticated'],
  // just like data, the prop can be used inside templates
  // and is also made available in the vm as this.message
  template: '<span>{{ authenticated }}</span>'
})
```

pass the `authenticated` from the root component from **App.vue**, like following:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <navigation :authenticated="authenticated"></navigation>
        <main>
        ....
        ....
```